# Can you please explain Lodash Iteratee function in English?

Tags: lodash

I'm trying to figure out how Lodash iteratee works and where I would use it.

> The documentation says:
>
> Creates a function that invokes func with the arguments of the created function. If func is a property name, the created function returns the property value for a given element. If func is an array or object, the created function returns true for elements that contain the equivalent source properties, otherwise it returns false.

This is one of the examples from the documentation, but I'm having some trouble wrapping my head around this.

```
var users = [
  { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 36, 'active': true },
  { 'user': 'fred',   'age': 40, 'active': false }
];

// The `_.matches` iteratee shorthand.
_.filter(users, _.iteratee({ 'user': 'barney', 'active': true }));
// => [{ 'user': 'barney', 'age': 36, 'active': true }]
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

An iteratee is basically a function. When you call lodash's [**iteratee**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#iteratee) function it returns a function that can be used later in the code.

There are 3 different type of iteratee which I'll describe in turn, using the following objects in the example code.

```
let mary = {
    name: 'mary',
    gender: 'female',
    age: 25,
    job: {
        title: 'teacher',
        salary: 10000
    }
}

let dave = {
    name: 'dave',
    gender: 'male',
    age: 27
}

let oswald = {
    name: 'oswald',
    gender: 'male',
    age: 25
}

let people = [mary, dave, oswald];
```

## 1. Property iteratee

When [**iteratee**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#iteratee) is called with a string, it returns a function that will return the property  of an object with the key of the supplied string.

e.g.

```
let getAge = _.iteratee('age');
```

What we end up with here is a function that returns the age property of an 
object. Something similar to:

```
function getAge(object){
    return object['age'];
}
```

So we can use `getAge` to return the age of people:

```
let marysage = getAge(mary);
let davesage = getAge(dave);
```

The string can also be a path to a property:

```
let jobtitle = _.iteratee('job.title');
```

## 2. Matches iteratee

When [**iteratee**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#iteratee) is called with an object, it returns a predicate (returns true or false) if an object has a matching key with the given value.

e.g.

```
let is25 = _.iteratee({age: 25});

let isMary25 = is25(mary);
let isDave25 = is25(dave);
```

The matches iteratee is not restricted to a single property. It can take multiple keys and values:

```
let isFemaleAged25 = _.iteratee({gender: 'female', age: 25});
```

## 3. Matches property iteratee

This is similar to the matches iteratee but is created when [**iteratee**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#iteratee) is called with an array of keys and values.

The `is25` function created above could also be created like so:

```
let is25 = _.iteratee(['age', 25]);
```

The properties can also be a path to a key, something which cannot be done using the matches iteratee:

```
let isTeacherAged25 = _.iteratee(['age', 25, 'job.title', 'teacher'])
```

## Using iteratees

Most of the time you won't call the [**iteratee**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#iteratee) function directly. Lodash will use the function internally when you call a function that can take an iteratee.

e.g.

```
let names = _.map(people, 'name'); // => ['mary', 'dave', 'oswald']
```

Here lodash will call `iteratee` with the string `name` and use it as the function to call map.

```
let peopleAged25 = _.filter(people, {age: 25 }); // mary and oswald
```

Here lodash will call `iteratee` with the object `{age: 25}` and use it as the function to filter the people collection.

Comment: awesome answer.Very detailed

Comment: It doesn't work with `_.negate()`, though.. Is there an easy way to negate an iteratee instead of `arg => arg.someKey != someValue`? I expected that `_.negate(['someKey', 'someValue'])` would do it. Particularly I'm interested in `_.without()` - the opposite of `_.filter()`. But without doesn't work with these types of iteratee too.

Comment: Have a look at [reject](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#reject) which is the opposite of filter.

Comment: Where the heck is this documented (The automatic calling of _.iteratee). There is a closed and locked issue (https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/3221) that mentions doc bloat, but no pointer to where it is actually documented

Comment: There must be a way to view these 3 distinct functionalities as one cohesive thing but I can't figure it out...

Comment: @cambunctious you could view them as overloads for a function that creates an iteratee.